# How could i use Email id as custom channel name using private_pub gem in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, private-pub

I am using private_pub gem for chat. When im using email_is of user as custom channel name it throws invalid channel error. How could i used email_id as channel name?

Answer (score 0):

the channel is url path like this `"/messages/new"`

So you would like the url to be `"/messages/:id/new"`

where :id = your email.

However you will have to escape the email first or hash it like this:

`CGI.escape email_address # to escape characters`

`Digest::SHA1.hexdigest email_address # to convert to SHA`